# Is there any way to create soft link using relative pathname? (not relative to home, or absolute)

Tags: linux, symlink

I tried using relative to pwd, but it doesn't work.

My current pwd is different from target path and original path (from where link need to be created).

I do not know the home directory so I cannot use relative-to-home pathname. Absolute pathname is not required.

How can I create soft link using relative pathname?

Answer (score 3):

A relative symlink is relative to its parent directory, that's irrelevant from the current directory of any process or the home directory of any user.

For instance, if `/some/dir/link` is a symlink to `../foo/bar`, then that's a symlink to `/some/dir/../foo/bar` (`/some/foo/bar` if `/some/dir` is not itself a symlink), regardless of what your current or home directory is.

If you want to create a new symlink to a file relative to the current directory (for instance the `bin/ls` file in your current `/home/stephane` directory), then you can do (in POSIX-like shells or `fish`):

```
ln -s -- "$PWD/bin/ls" /some/dir/link
```

Which would create an absolute symlink (to `/home/stephane/bin/ls`). To create a relative symlink, you'd need:

```
ln -s ../../home/stephane/bin/ls /some/dir/link
```

(assuming `/some` and `/some/dir` are not themselves  symlinks)

GNU `ln` has a `-r` option to help you compute that path:

```
ln -rs bin/ls /some/dir/link
```

(which would create the same symlink to `../../home/stephane/bin/ls`).

Answer (score 1):

You can do symlink using relative path

e.g. (you want to create symbolic link from folder `bb` which is located in `../../bb` related to the current working directory to `mylink`

```
ln -s ../../bb/ mylink

$ ls -lsa mylink
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 9 Apr 18 15:51 mylink -> ../../bb/
```

Another example where mylink is in a related folder for `pwd`

```
mkdir ../../tst
$ ln -s ../../bb/ ../../tst/mylink
$ ls -lsa ../../tst/mylink
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 9 Apr 18 16:08 ../../tst/mylink -> ../../bb/
```

Comment: The path for 'mylink' should also be relative to pwd. It works in the case where we know the full path. But, I dont know the full path to the location, not even home directory.

Comment: the path to mylink is indeed related to pwd. In the example i provided I didn't use *full path* nor *home directory*

Comment: The location where link needs to be created is not in pwd, it is outside pwd.

Comment: @HarshPatel - I've added another example, where the target link is related to `pwd`

Comment: I appreciate, but the location where it needs to created is outside pwd. For example `./../../location`.

Comment: @HarshPatel - updated the example to be `../../location`

Comment: It does not work like that, I tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57290/discussion-between-yaron-and-harsh-patel).